# OnMouseDown Doesn't Work for Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a div with a `onmousedown` but the click is not getting recognized. No alert is popping up. Here is a codepen with a working example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzYpb?editors=110

Here is the code sample.

```
  <ion-header class="bar bar-subheader">
    <div class="title">
      the cool title
    </div>
    <div onmousedown="alert(1)" id="filter-button">
      <span class="assertive">
          <i class="icon ion-arrow-down-b"></i>
          CLICK ME
        </span>
    </div>
  </ion-header>
```

CSS

```
#filter-button {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```

Why is this not working and how do I fix it?

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/a2k4njgL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow floating this div (#filter-button) causes it not receiving click events, but you can fix that with following css:

```
#filter-button {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute; //changed position to absolute and removed float
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 12px;        //changed from padding right to positioning 12px from right edge
}
```

Now it works like a charm - [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdOzaN?editors=110)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.title` element is overlapping your filter button. To make your filter button above the `.title` element you need to set `z-index: 1` to it.

E.g.

```
#filter-button {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  position: relative; /* need this for z-index to work */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPXdYq)

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
<html></html>
```

tags around that and it worked perfectly!

Check the browser's console to see if you have bad javascript code elsewhere that's preventing that one from running?

[image]

Comment: You did not look at my codepen which provides the full example.

Comment: I think it's useful to isolate the code example as much as possible -- so I usually just try c/ping only the relevant html to make sure there's no problem there

Answer (score -1):

**See example..........**

```html
<div onmousedown="alert('onmousedown workinkg')" id="add id" class="add class">
Mousedown Test <br/>
Add any code and tag Here....
</div>
```